# Move 2 scroll bar at same time in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

In my Vuetify project I have a 2 `DIV` in a splitpane wrapped in 2 scroll panes. How can I scroll both scroll panes at the same time. Or simply bind scroll bar to other scroll bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could match the scrollTop properties

```
const box1 = document.querySelector('.box1')
const box2 = document.querySelector('.box2')

box1.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  box2.scrollTop = box1.scrollTop;
});
```